# Capturing group regex with grep

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to capture SQL DDL "CREATE" from a PostgreSQL schema dump that looks like this:

```sql
SET default_table_access_method = heap;

CREATE TABLE schema_name.table_name (
    col1 bigint,
    col2 text
);

ALTER TABLE schema_name.table_name OWNER TO user;

CREATE INDEX index ON schema_name.table_name USING btree (col1);
```

What I want is:

```
CREATE TABLE schema_name.table_name (
    col1 bigint,
    col2 text
);`
```

Why `grep -Po "(CREATE TABLE)[\S\s]*(;)" dump.sql` is not working?

In PCRE2 `/CREATE TABLE [\w]*\.[\w]*[\S\s]*(;)/U` matches properly.

thanks.

Comment: *"Why the regex is not working?"* : You need to add `-z` option to enable multiline grep. Also if you want to use `.*?` to match any character you need to use the `s` modifier (see [Modifiers](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers) `perlre`). For example: `grep -zPo "(?s)CREATE TABLE.*?;" dump.sql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` would be better tool for this:

```sh
sed -n '/^CREATE TABLE/,/;$/p' file.sql

CREATE TABLE schema_name.table_name (
    col1 bigint,
    col2 text
);
```

If you really want a `gnu-grep` solution then use:

```sh
grep -zPo "(?m)^CREATE TABLE[^;]+;\R" file.sql

CREATE TABLE schema_name.table_name (
    col1 bigint,
    col2 text
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unsure about your regex, but this works:

```
grep -Poz "CREATE TABLE[^;]*;" dump.sql
```

Gives:

```
CREATE TABLE schema_name.table_name (
    col1 bigint,
    col2 text
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is tagged `perl`... here's a quick script using an old but nifty module I found, [`SQL::Script`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Script), to parse the SQL dump:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use SQL::Script; # Install with your favorite CPAN client

# Pass the dump file name as the command-line argument

my $script = SQL::Script->new;
$script->read($ARGV[0]);
foreach my $stmt ($script->statements) {
    say "$stmt;" if $stmt =~ /^CREATE TABLE/i;
}
```

Example:

```sh
$ ./dump_tables test.sql
CREATE TABLE schema_name.table_name (
    col1 bigint,
    col2 text
);
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk` you could try following `awk` program.

```
awk -v RS='\nCREATE[^)]*\n\\);' 'RT{gsub(/(^|$)\n/,"",RT);print RT}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using GNU `awk`, setting `RS` variable of `awk` to `\nCREATE[^)]*\n\\);` to get only required part in shown samples. Then in main program checking condition if RT is NOT NULL then removing starting and ending lines from it and printing it, to get only needed part out of sql's output.